# laravel 5 pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a friendlist for a user
so a user can have many friends

but for calling the friends I'm having trouble getting my relation right:

```
user
  id

friends
  user_id
  friend_user_id
```

Class user:

```
public function Friends(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'friends');
}
```

So `Auth::User()->Friends` should return a list of `User` models

Comment: Please give more information:
- Are friends also of class "User" or a seperate class "Friend"?

Comment: User is the only class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't have a "one to many" relationship but rather "many to many" with `friends` being your joining table

Try this:

```
public function Friends(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a relation to the same model, you would do something like this:

Models/User.cs

```
public function Friends()
{
   return $this->hasMany('User', 'user_friend_of', 'id'); // assuming user_friend_of is the FK on user-table
}

public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

This would mean you have only 1 table, which has a foreign key to another row in the same table, for instance: (id - name - user_friend_of )

Answer (score 0):

In your user class, define the function as follows:

```
public function Friends(){
    return $this->hasMany('friends');
}
```

Calling $user->Friends()->get() should return you everything you need. Note that 'friends' should be the name of the table.